# pass a function to navigation component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a question related to react native navigation

```
const Swipe = ({signUp}) => {
    const Stack= createStackNavigator()
    return(
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator screenOptions= {{headerBackTitleStyle:{color:'white'}}}>

                <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" options={
                    {
                        headerStyle: {
                            backgroundColor: Color.Primary
                        },
                    }
                }>
                   {
                       ()=>(
                           <SignUp signUp={signUp}/>
                       )
                   }
                     </Stack.Screen>
                <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignIn}  options= {
                  ({navigation, route})=> ({
                      HeaderTitle: ()=> route.params.name,
                      headerStyle: {
                          backgroundColor: Color.Primary
                      }
                  })
                }/>
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
export default Swipe

in the root app:
<Swipe signUp= {signUp}/>
```

the question is when i pass signUp function to the navigation 
it works but when i navigate to signIn component it shows that there is an error to navigate which is undefined object

can any one help me

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you did not give signin component as a props? like:

```
const Swipe = ({signUp, signIn}) => {
 const Stack= createStackNavigator()
  return(........)
})
```

Comment: can you explain more i din't get it

Comment: you did not pass signin component to Swipe component as a parameter. You should also pass signin l
Your code : const Swipe = ({signUp}) => ..... 
My suggestion: const Swipe = ({signUp, SignIn}) => .......

Comment: i imported sign in component, the parameter signUp is just a function to write in the console